# Is there any way to create an executable file using c++ and an online IDE

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, ide, notepad++, online-compilation

So here's the situation. I have been using ms access vba for automation at my job. I have access to ms access and notepad++ only with the nppexec plugin. However, g++ is not installed as far as I can tell.

I am looking to use ui automation event handlers but those do not work in vba. Since I have notepad++ i can write out c++ and make that work but in the end, i would like to produce a one click .exe file that runs the add event handlers objects.

The issue is that i cannot compile or run without g++. However I can if I use an online ide. I just need one that will let me download the resulting exe file.

Is there any such tool? Either that or a way to get g++ onto a computer without installing. (Permissions issues)

Thank you.

Comment: Online IDEs allow you to compile and execute your code within that IDE. They do not produce executable files that you can download and use. Even if you could, it would be more difficult to do that than it would be to install g++ on your own machine instead. You'd need the same permissions to download and run that app as you would to download and run g++.

Comment: Online compilers generally do not produce EXEs that can then be downloaded.  They only work online, and have a very limited subset of features for online use.  However, there are plenty of free compilers readily available that you can download and install locally, g++ is not the only one.

Comment: Let's assume there is an executable. However online IDE might be linux and its executable is not executable on your OS (windows). What you really need might be a server for compilation but it could be overkilled.

Comment: Why not visual studio c++, out of curiosity?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. It seems that the consensus is "No". The main issue is that I cannot install any additional software such as visual studio or g++. Whatever I use must be fully functional at download, such as nppexec plugins which Just require unzipping. If i could get a functional source of g++, i would be golden. As to installing VS, well that would be installing I am afraid. The solution that I have come to is to use an ide to run code to ensure functionality and then share it and compile on a personal computer. Then upload an exe to GitHub so it can be downloaded whole.